# Running Angular Code from Strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to achieve a similar result to codepen or jsfiddle, where you can type some code and it gets executed afterwards.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6313/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

// Lists all registered Directives for any angular module..
function Directives(module) {
    var directives = [];
    var invokes = angular.module(module)._invokeQueue;
    for (var i in invokes) {
        if (invokes[i][1] === "controller") directives.push(invokes[i][2]);
    }
    return directives;
}
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$compile,$timeout,$rootScope,$injector){
  var module = "angular.module('myApp').controller('myDynamicCtrl', function($scope) {console.log('hello');window.myScope = $scope; $scope.hello = 'User!';});";
  (new Function(module)());

  // I can access the new controller via:
  myApp._invokeQueue[1][2][1]($scope);
  console.log(window.myScope);

  var html = angular.element("<div ng-controller='myDynamicCtrl'; id='appended'>Hello {{hello}}</div>");
  angular.element(document.getElementById('target')).append(html);

  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('appended')).scope();
  angular.element(document.getElementById('appended')).replaceWith($compile(html)(window.myScope));  


});
```

I can execute the controller defined in a string and it gets registered properly to my angular module.

However, If I link it to a html element, the newly created controller is undefined.

I want to achieve the same result for directives as well (define directive as string, execute it, and compile a html with it).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work (including controllers and directives):
Bootstrapping the first app manually instead of using `ng-app` did the trick for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6318/